# Meaning of "unchubby" in "If you are gay, why were you so unchubby in the shower?"

Tags: word-meaning, slang

I am watching a movie and this sentence is from the movie.

> If you are gay, why were you so unchubby in the shower?

What does unchubby mean? since I did not find it in the dictionary.

Comment: It doesn't change anything significantly, but the quote seems to be from the movie "[I Love You, Beth Cooper](http://www.allreadable.com/mv11754IVwU)," and both the transcript and the [quotes list](http://www.subzin.com/quotes/M52737de69/I+Love+You%2C+Beth+Cooper/Heh%2C+heh%2C+I--+I+was+just+being+cool.) I found online actually give it as "If you're **not** gay, why so
unchubby in the shower?" (Apparently the boy being addressed was showering with the girl speaking)

Answer (score 20):

I looked up some slang dictionaries: **[pop a chubby](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=pop+a+chubby)**, **[chubby](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=chubby)**.

It was news to me that this word had this slang meaning: to have an erection.

So, quite logically, "unchubby" means "without an erection".

The original sentence could be transformed into:

> If you are gay, why **didn't you have an erection** in the shower?

A gay person might have an erection from looking at other naked males in the shower.

Comment: Good answer, however it's worth noting that quote is originally "If you **are not** gay...". Like sumelic said, the boy being addressed was showering with the girl speaking, so I would assume she means "If you're not gay, why do you not have an erection from looking at me?"